# Python-sklearn pre-trained RandomForest not working on Raspbian Pi (Raspbian Jessie)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, scikit-learn, random-forest

I trained a RandomForest model on my Ubuntu-16.04 desktop system (in Python-sklearn). Then, I ported this trained model on my Raspberry Pi 3 (having Raspbian Jessie OS). But this pre-trained RandomForest model is not working on Raspbian, giving error: "did not recognize loaded array layout".

Version of packages (like sklearn, pandas, numpy, pickle) are exactly same on my Raspberry Pi and desktop system.

Still I am getting this error.

Thanks

Comment: If those versions are really the same, the only remaining source of problems are: 32-bit vs. 64-bit; arm vs. x86 and co, (architecture-differences). Look up sklearn + pickle/serialization at sklearn's issues @ github. I would expect some discussions there.

Comment: I am pretty sure that issue is not because of 32bit and 64bit. I already faced the issue of 32bit and 64bit, so I trained a model on 32bit (as raspberry pi is also 32bit). I trained model on Ubuntu 16.04 (32bit). But still I am facing this issue. At various other online places, I read only one solution: to match version of Python packages. I did this but still issue persists. And one more thing: pip is not working on raspbian jessie. Giving OSError. Not installing any Python package.

Comment: How are you storing the samples? Try using a simple .csv and training directly at the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: I have data of size 7.5 GB. Thanks for your suggestion but I don't think that training a model on raspberry pi for such a huge data is a good idea. Thanks @DenisCandido :-)

Comment: @sansingh: could you solve the problem? even i want to run a random forest on raspberry pi

Comment: @user27665 Unfortunately no. I opted an alternate solution. But in case you want to train RandomForest on RaspberryPi, then you can explore tensorflow RandomForest (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/tensor_forest). I hope that you knows that tensorflow is now officially supported in RaspberryPi (https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_raspbian). If possible then please share your experience about tensorflow RandomForest. All the best!!!